# Interpolation not working in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an Angular project that I am working on and for some reason interpolation is not working in one particular component. I have tried comparing this component with the other components within the project but they are identical. However, it is not working. I have copied the component.ts and component.html files below. What am I doing incorrectly?

members.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { moveIn, fallIn, moveInLeft } from '../router.animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-members',
  templateUrl: './members.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./members.component.css'],
  animations: [moveIn(), fallIn(), moveInLeft()],
  host: {'[@moveIn]': ''}
})
export class MembersComponent implements OnInit {

  name: any;
  state = '';
  test = 'test2';

  constructor(public af: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) {

    this.af.authState.subscribe(auth => {
      if (auth) {
        this.name = af.auth.currentUser;
        console.log('Display Name: ' + this.name.displayName);
      }
    });

  }

  logout() {
     this.af.auth.signOut();
     console.log('logged out');
     this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

members.component.html

```
<div class="form-container" id="toolbar">
  <header [@fallIn]="state">
    <button (click)="logout()" class="basic-btn">Logout</button>
  </header>
  <div id="page" [@moveInLeft]="state">
    <h2>Hey {{ this.name.displayname }}!</h2>

    <p>This is a test {{ test }}</p>

    <img src="/src/assets/images/filler.png" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What is this `console.log('Display Name: ' + this.name.displayName);` printing to the console?

Comment: It is printing the display name correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really think that's how you get the currently logged-in user details. These details are present in `authState` which is a Promise and not an Observable. I wonder how you're able to see the user details in the console.

Also, you're using `{{ this.name.displayname }}` in the interpolation syntax. You should be using `{{ name.displayName}}`. The name will initially be `undefined`. And then once the Promise value is resolved, it will get populated. But till then, the template will start getting rendered. To avoid any errors on the console for that, also place an `*ngIf="name"` on the wrapping div. Or better, use an `async` pipe to unwrap the value of `authState`

Do this in `ngOnInit` instead of the `constructor`

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { moveIn, fallIn, moveInLeft } from '../router.animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-members',
  templateUrl: './members.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./members.component.css'],
  animations: [moveIn(), fallIn(), moveInLeft()],
  host: {
    '[@moveIn]': ''
  }
})
export class MembersComponent implements OnInit {

  user;
  state = '';
  test = 'test2';

  constructor(public af: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router) { }

  logout() {
    this.af.auth.signOut();
    console.log('logged out');
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.user = this.af.authState;
  }

}
```

In template use

```
<div 
  class="form-container" 
  id="toolbar" 
  *ngIf="user | async as currentUser">
  <header [@fallIn]="state">
    <button (click)="logout()" class="basic-btn">Logout</button>
  </header>
  <div id="page" [@moveInLeft]="state">
    <h2>Hey {{ currentUser.displayName }}!</h2>
    <p>This is a test {{ test }}</p>
    <img src="/src/assets/images/filler.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

without `this`

Comment: I am still having the same issue. The display name gets printed to the console but the template items do not get replaced.

Comment: There's also an issue with the case:

`displayName` should be used instead of `displayname`

Comment: Did this fix your issue?

Comment: No it did not. Neither displayName nor test are showing. displayName gets printed to the console correctly but it does not appear webpage.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making a asynchronicity call so the template could not retrieve the value since the http request didn't complete.

Wrap your `div` in an `*ngIf` statement, and in a template you refer to a variable without using `this.`:

```
<div class="form-container" id="toolbar" *ngIf="name">
  <header [@fallIn]="state">
    <button (click)="logout()" class="basic-btn">Logout</button>
  </header>
  <div id="page" [@moveInLeft]="state">
    <h2>Hey {{ name.displayname }}!</h2>

    <p>This is a test {{ test }}</p>

    <img src="/src/assets/images/filler.png" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I am still having the same issue. The display name gets printed to the console but the template items do not get replaced.

Comment: actually, I'm getting the same problem on Angular 6. I wrapped the div in *ngIf, and like you, I see the value on the console, but it does not get rendered on the page. I'm guessing that we've somehow broken the template in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on an h2 element and just wrapped *ngIf on the h2 and it worked